# Efficient way to truncate a std::vector<char> to length N - to free memory

Tags: c++, windows, vector, stl, stdvector

I have several large std::vectors of chars (bytes loaded from binary files).

When my program runs out of memory, I need to be able to cull some of the memory used by these vectors. These vectors are almost the entirety of my memory usage, and they're just caches for local and network files, so it's safe to just grab the largest one and chop it in half or so.

Only thing is, I'm currently using vector::resize and vector::shrink_to_fit, but this seems to require more memory (I imagine for a reallocation of the new size) and then a bunch of time (for destruction of the now destroyed pointers, which I thought would be free?) and then copying the remaining to the new vector. Note, this is on Windows platform, in debug, so the pointers might not be destroyed in the Release build or on other platforms.

Is there something I can do to just say "C++, please tell the OS that I no longer need the memory located past location N in this vector"?

Alternatively, is there another container I'd be better off using? I do need to have random access though, or put effort into designing a way to easily keep iterators pointing at the place I'll want to read next, which would be possible, just not easy, so I'd prefer not using a std::list.

Comment: the vector of *pointers* really eats most of your memory?

Comment: It is more likely that those objects these pointers point to are the major memory consumers.

Comment: This changes everything, and nothing. I completely goofed - they're actually vectors of chars, bytes loaded from binary files.

Comment: "When my program runs out of memory,..." I'd suggest you start with finding out why *that* happens first. A better explanation of the real problem, "Why do I run out of process memory?" with a detailed explanation and divulgence of the code that causes this would probably be more productive.

Comment: I already know why I run out of memory. I am loading files into memory for caching purposes. These vectors make up "the cache". I would prefer to use as much memory as possible for these caches, to reduce the chance of needing to going back to IO on the files. When I need to load a file that isn't in the cache, I need to free up some cache space to make room for the new entry. I would like the freeing of space in the cache to be more performant.
I was using a collection of vectors of chars to be an easy way to avoid having to write my own cache class, which would be far more complicated, AFAIK

Comment: What I mean is, there's probably some areas where I'm simply wasting memory, but not to a great enough degree to make up for the fact that I'm fundamentally trying to load more bytes into memory than bytes of RAM my computer actually has, yet the program shouldn't crash, or be too slow about it.

Comment: Somewhat related note: all modern operating systems already cache files, so a new read of a recently used file normally incurs just in the cost of the syscalls trapping in kernel mode.

Comment: I'll have to compare the performance of that at some point

Comment: Actually, to be honest all this smells of premature optimization. File caching is a job usually best left to the operating system, since it often has more knowledge than you about how much memory there is to spare for this, how much memory is being used by other processes, what are the most accessed files, ... For a "normal" application you want to do things "the normal way" and try to optimize this only if you see an actual bottleneck.

Comment: Quite possibly, but this project is as much to learn as it is to solve a practical problem. I still want to know the answer to the question and I still want to implement a cache for the purposes described. I am interested in comparing the performance later, to see how I did.

Answer (score 4):

`resize` and `shrink_to_fit` are your best bets, as long as we are talking about standard C++, but these, as you noticed may not help at all if you are in a low memory situation to begin with: since the allocator interface do not provide a `realloc`-like operation, vector is forced to allocate a new block, copy the data in it and deallocate the old block.

Now, I see essentially four easy ways out:

- drop whole vectors, not just parts of them, possibly using an LRU or stuff like that; working with big vectors, the C++ allocator normally just forwards to the OS's memory management calls, so the memory should go right back to the OS;
- write your own container which uses `malloc`/`realloc`, or OS-specific functionality;
- use `std::deque` instead; you lose guaranteed contiguousness of data, but, since deques normally allocate the space for data in distinct chunks, doing a `resize`+`shrink_to_fit` should be quite cheap - simply all the unused blocks at the end are freed, with no need for massive reallocations;
- just leave this job to the OS. As already stated in the comments, the OS already has a file cache, and in normal cases it can handle it better than you or me, even just for the fact that it has a better vision of how much *physical* memory is left for that, what files are "hot" for most applications, and so on. Also, since you are working in a virtual address space you cannot even guarantee that your memory will actually stay in RAM; the very moment that the machine goes in memory pressure and you aren't using some memory pages so often, they get swapped to disk, so all your performance gain is lost (and you wasted space on the paging file for stuff that is already found on disk).

An additional way may be to just use memory mapped files - the system will do its own caching as usual, but you avoid any syscall overhead as long as the file remains in memory.

Comment: std::deque sounded quite promising, but I am directly reading the file into the vector currently, which I can't do with a deque. I might have to look into the memory mapped files solution, or just do a drop of the vector instead. If all else fails, I just go back to direct memory access.

Answer (score 2):

std::vector::shrink_to_fit() cannot result in more memory being used, if so it's a bug.

C++11 defines shrink_to_fit() as follows:

void shrink_to_fit(); Remarks: shrink_to_fit is a non-binding request to reduce capacity() to size(). [ Note: The request is non-binding to allow latitude for implementation-specific optimizations. — end note ]

As the note indicates, shrink_to_fit() may, but not necessarily, actually free memory, and the standard gives C++ implementations a free hand to recycle and optimize memory usage internally, as they see fit. C++ does not make it mandatory for shrink_to_fit(), and the like, to result in actually memory being released to the operating system, and in many cases the C++ runtime library may not actually be able to, as I'll get to in a moment. The C++ runtime library is allowed to take the freed memory, and stash it away internally, and reuse it automatically for the future memory allocation requests (explicit news, or container growth).

Most modern operating systems are not designed to allocate and release memory blocks of arbitrary sizes. Details differ, but typically an operating system allocates and deallocates memory in even chunks, typically 4Kb, or larger, at even memory page addresses. If you allocate a new object that's only a few hundred bytes long, the C++ library will request an entire page of memory to be allocated, take the first hundred bytes of it for the new object, then keep the spare amount of memory for future new requests.

Similarly, even if shrink_to_fit(), or delete, frees up a few hundred bytes, it can't go back to the operating system immediately, but only when an entire 4kb continuous memory range (or whatever is the allocation page size used by the operating system) -- suitably aligned -- is completely unused at all. Only then can a process release that page back to the operating system. Until then, the library keeps track of freed memory ranges, to be used for future new requests, without asking the operating system to allocate more pages of memory to the process.

Comment: Thanks for this. Is shrink_to_fit() allowed to temporarily, internally, use more memory? I think that's what's happening in my case. Once the call is complete, I am left with the same or less memory usage than I started, but while it's happening, I can see an increase.

Also, in my usage, the shrink is usually on the orders of hundreds of MB or larger, so the details of limitations of memory allocations are interesting and appreciated, but probably not related to my issue in this specific case.

Comment: If the allocator interface is the same as it was in C++03, `shrink_to_fit` cannot possibly do its task (if it chooses to do it) without first allocating the new (shorter) block of memory, since allocators cannot expose a `realloc`-like interface. Also, while it's true that freed blocks go back to the allocator, normally C++ allocators manage their own heap for smaller allocations, and leave big stuff to the operating system.

Comment: That's what I was thinking